# SQL pointer to fallback to other status

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I was just trying to get some pointers on my requirement. One part of my requirement is that I have a record in table A with say orderNumber. I have another table say TableB with amount with each orderNumber and its status. I have to pick the amount from table B based on following condition:

- lets say the order status is completed pick up the amount from that
  row
- if you can not find the order in completed state, fallback to
  closed state and pick up the amount from it.

I am not so expert in SQL and any pointer on how we can achieve this fallback behavior with SQL will be of great help.

Table A:

```
OrderNo
1234
12345
```

TableB:

```
OrderNo  Status     Amount
1234     Closed     123
1234    Completed   130
12345    Closed     200
```

Result should be

```
1234 -> 130
12345 -> 200
```

Since 12345 does not have completed status in tableB we fell back to closed status.

Comment: First, you shall not use mysql and sql-server tags at the same time, choose only the one your system uses. Second, I don't understand; what are the "completed" and "closed" states? Is TableA the closed and TableB the completed?

Comment: Add Sample data and expected result(Not Images) for better understanding of your issue. Data speak more than your words.

Comment: Thanks Guys! Sorry for being vague in the question at first place. Have added one small example to explain the usecase